# Do I need to do more prep work on this cement floor before putting in new tile?

Tags: concrete, flooring, tile, basement

In my basement i have a poured concrete floor, and we're re-doing the bathroom down there. It used to have Vinyl flooring, and we ripped it all up. The top vinyl part came up easily, but it left a bit of the paper backing glued to the floor. I've scraped as much as i can, but there's still a thin layer remaining. I'm wondering if I need do anything more, or if it will be ok to put down tile over top of that?

Any thoughts or suggestions?

**Edit:** Would it be worthwhile to throw a coat of paint over it to clean things up a bit? Just thinking out loud....

Comment: No painting a floor before a tile installation is definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper backing can be cleaned off with a solvent paint stripper and then wash the old glue off with trisodium phosphate and a scrub brush. Then wash several times with water to remove the residue of both operations. Tile thin set in most cases may not adhere to old glue, especially if you have to use unmodified thin set because you are planning on using an uncoupling membrane like DITRA.